# Python Map or Filter function with variable assignment

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Is there a way to use either of the map or filter functions to map a list of variables to a function and assign a variable (the name of the variable) to each of those outputs?

```
    mapping_tables = ['Assets_Table','Liabilities_Table','Equity_Table','Income_Table']
```

I have a list of tables that I'm applying to a function which will convert it into a dataframe and then assign a variable to the dataframe from the list of mapping_tables. At the moment the following 'for loop' works.

```
for table_name in mapping_tables:
    globals()[table_name] = load_data_table_to_df(sheet_name, table_name)
```

Is there a way to optimize this? Perhaps using one of the Map or Filter functions? or even a different python library? Or is this as simple as it gets?

Thank you

Comment: Ooof. No. Do not do this. Store your "variables" in a dictionary, and modify them that way. Don't use `globals()` like this.

Comment: Also, no... `filter` is used for, well, filtering.

Comment: `tables = {table: load_data_table_to_df(sheet_name, table) for table in mapping_tables}`

Comment: @Thyebri first, that's a `dict` comprehension. Second, the whole point of using a `dict` is to allow for named-access to OP's data *without dynamically creating variables*.

Comment: @ddejohn I know it is a dict comprehension, I posted that comment before I saw the code in full, and when I saw the code in full I immediately realized my mistake so I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use `map()`:

```py
# Assuming `sheet_name` is defined somewhere...
def table_to_df(table_name):
    return table_name, load_data_to_df(sheet_name, table_name)


frames = dict(map(table_to_df, mapping_tables))
```

Then when you want to work on one of your dataframes:

```py
frames[table_name]
```

Comment: It doesn't have to involve using map(), I just want a more efficient/correct way of dealing with variable assignment and mapping a function.